# How to pass a variable in jAlert from a php file

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a bad time trying to implement some translating files into a site of mine. The deal is to translate the whole site with a php that contains the name of the language that will be used (ex. en.php, es.php, pt.php...) and set variables into this files that will be called as soon as the user click the diferente language names into the webpage. No problem until then.

These languages variables are defined in these php file like this...

On pt.php:

```
define('TEXTO_69','Gostaria de se identificar?');
```

On en.php:

```
define('TEXTO_69','Would you like to identify yourself?');
```

And so on every php language file...

The main problem i am having is not to have acess to these variables in my index.php file when i am editing the script part, take a look:

```
if($('input[name="agree"]').is(':checked')) {
        //alert('Checkbox is checked!!');
        return true;
    } else { 
        jAlert('Para efetuar o cadastro voc&ecirc; deve estar de acordo com os termos de uso e politica de privacidade','Aviso');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

I want to replace the string *'Para efetuar o cadastro você deve estar de acordo com os termos de uso e politica de privacidade'* and the string *'Aviso'* with texts in my defined variables (ex. TEXTO_69) back in the languages files.

Opening a php inside the javascript function JAlert and echoing the variable does not return the string.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you try `jAlert("<?php echo TEXTO_69; ?>")` ??

Comment: Thanks bud! Worked like a charm!... Got no experience in php and javascript so that was a headache to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by including double quotes ("") in variable declaration inside jAlert...

Before (WRONG):

```
jAlert(<?php echo TEXTO_69; ?>)
```

After (RIGHT!)

```
jAlert("<?php echo TEXTO_69; ?>")
```

:)